# Why do my Razor Page methods not get called?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I cannot get Razor Pages to work. It will display the Index page and thats it. No links work on the page and no data will display. All Helper Methods are completely ignored by the compiler, it will not even highlight them in a different colour.

When the page loads it will call the Get function and the page will display, but none of the functionality on the view works. I have deleted everything so I just have 1 page with a couple of post buttons on it, and still it will not call the Post method. Does anyone have any idea what is going on?

Here is my View:

```html
@page
@model FloorCore.Areas.Jobs.Pages.JobIndexModel
@{
}

<form method="post">
    <button class="btn btn-default">Click to post</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Click to post</button>
</form>
```

Here is the controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace FloorCore.Areas.Jobs.Pages
{
    public class JobIndexModel : PageModel
    {
        public void OnGet()
        {
            int for_breakpoint = 0;
        }

        public void OnPost()
        {
            int for_breakpoint  = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Clicking on either button just returns:
This page isn’t working. 
If the problem continues, contact the site owner.
HTTP ERROR 400

The OnPost method on the controller is not called.

Comment: Reference [Introduction to Razor Pages in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages)

Comment: A 400 status is bad request: likely there is an issue being picked up before ASP.NET would call your model's method.

Comment: @SimonBailey you are definitely missing a `[HttpPost]` attribute decorator for OnPost() action because you are using post method in form `<form method="post">`. You also need `asp-action='yourAction'`  attribute in form tag. Not to mention that you have to check your models as stated before.

Answer (score 2):

I came back to answer my own question because I figured out what the problem was and perhaps this will help someone else. I was missing the _ViewImports file in this particular Area.

The _ViewImports contained the following line:

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

which I needed in order for my helper methods to work.

Comment: ALl the guides I saw had no mention of this taghelper file. It makes sense logically but when following guides there was not much help. You saved me a lot of time and headaches maybe a few beers as well.