# Unable to get the id from OnGet method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have this URL https://localhost:44314/Identity/Role/Edit?id=408112a5-4fc9-4660-b308-b68d84f035b6

The problem is when I put a breakpoint for these 2 methods, it did stops at `EditModel` but not `OnGet`. This is a Razor Page (not MVC).

No error. It just load the razor page but it didn't reach onget method.

If I change URL to https://localhost:44314/Identity/Role/Edit, it can reach `OnGet`.

If I change URL to https://localhost:44314/Identity/Role/Edit/408112a5-4fc9-4660-b308-b68d84f035b6, then the error become `This localhost page can’t be found`

I believe it has to do with routing because the conventional routing is `controller`/`action` while over here since I have `area`, it becomes `identity`/`controller`/`action`

But, I still could not find the solution for this. Anyone can help?

```
public class EditModel : PageModel
{
    public EditModel()
    {
    }

    public void OnGet(string id)
    {            
    }
}
```

Comment: what response do you get btw?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do my Razor Page methods not get called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58008577/why-do-my-razor-page-methods-not-get-called)

Comment: Nothing in `https://localhost:44314/Identity/Role/Edit` says to hit this method here, please add more details

Comment: No error. It just load the razor page but without reaching onget method first

Comment: Does the .cshtml page include @page "{id:string}" at the top?

Comment: @BradPatton after adding it, it hits `InvalidOperationException: The constraint reference 'string' could not be resolved to a type. Register the constraint type with 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteOptions.ConstraintMap'.`

Comment: Steve I copied that from a page where I have @page "{id:int}". Forgot string is the default and not needed. Glad you got it solved

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved after adding `@page "{id}"` in Edit.cshtml. More explanation [here](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/310/routing-in-razor-pages)